# Loop through two lists where one is smaller than the other

Tags: python

I have two lists where one list is a list of tuples (will call it `list2`), and another is a list of strings (will call it `list1`).

`list1` is smaller than `list2` but I want to be able to loop through them both and compare values from `list1` in each tuple that is in `list2`.

So far I have been managing to get results but it does not have the in the correct order.

My code so far is;

```
list1 = ['2018-24', '2018-23', '2018-22', '2018-21', '2018-20', '2018-19', '2018-18', '2018-17', '2018-16', '2018-15', '2018-14', '2018-13', '2018-12', '2018-11']

list2 = [(27, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-7'), (5, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-2'), (4, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-6'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-10'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-14'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-50'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-12'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-4'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-5'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-3'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-51'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-13'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-11')]

new_list = []

for x in list2:
    ii = x[2].split(' ')[2]
    if ii not in list1:
        new_list.append(0)
    else:

        print('This is ii ' + ii)
        for y in list1:
            if ii in y:
                new_list.append(x[0]) 
print(new_list)
print(len(new_list))
print(len(list1))
o/p > 
'This is ii 2018-14'
'This is ii 2018-13'
'This is ii 2018-12'
'This is ii 2018-11'
[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
13
14
```

It can be seen above that the len of the `new_list` and `list1` are different they should both be the same. But also it can be seen that the order of the `new_list` does not match up with the `list1` values so for example the value at index 3 of the `new_list` should actually be at index 10. I am not sure why it seems to be re-ordering the `new_list`.

The output I am expecting to get is `new_list` and `list1` to be the same lengths, but to also have corresponding values, so for example if `ii in y` was true and `ii` was `2018-14` then when taking into consideration index 10 for both `new_list` and `list1` the values respectively should be `3` and `2018-14`, another example of the expected output if considering index 0 of both `new_list` and `list1` then the values respectively should be `0` and `2018-7`.

A full breakdown of expected outputs is listed below;

```
list1 = ['2018-24', '2018-23', '2018-22', '2018-21', '2018-20', '2018-19', '2018-18', '2018-17', '2018-16', '2018-15', '2018-14', '2018-13', '2018-12', '2018-11']

new_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Can you post both of your lists as well?

Comment: @SijanBhandari have amended

Comment: You should probably be using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: `if ii not in list` - do you mean `list1`, `list2`, or `new_list`?

Comment: You're appending one entry to `new_list` for each entry in `list2`. It's unclear why you expect `new_list` to have the same length as `list1` instead.

Comment: `list2`'s length is 13 and `list1`'s length is 14. Please check.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did think to use `zip` but then thought it would not work as the list lengths were different sizes. Would it be better practice to use `zip`?

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani I did mention this in my original post, will have another look

Comment: In your output, "2018-13" corresponds to "3". Can you explain why this is? I would think it ought to correspond to "1", since `list2` contains `(1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-13')`.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, was a typo, "2018-13" should correspond to "1".

Comment: **@Kevin**, in your question, you've mentioned list of tuples as `list1` but in your code it is list of strings. The same is for `list2`. Please clear it.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani Did you mean to ping me? If so have amended question.

Comment: **@Kevin**, thanks, now it is clear. Let me try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no repeats in the third elements of `list2`, I'd be inclined to put them into a dictionary that maps dates to numbers. Then you can iterate through `list1` and fetch those numbers out of the dictionary, using `0` as a fallback value if the date doesn't exist.

```
d = {description.split(' ')[2]: number for number, _, description in list2}
result = [d.get(date, 0) for date in list1]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['2018-24', '2018-23', '2018-22', '2018-21', '2018-20', '2018-19', '2018-18', '2018-17', '2018-16', '2018-15', '2018-14', '2018-13', '2018-12', '2018-11']
list2 = [(27, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-7'), (5, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-2'), (4, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-6'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-10'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-14'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-50'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-12'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-4'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-5'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-3'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-51'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-13'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-11')]
new_list = []

for x in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        ii = list2[x][2].split(' ')[2]
        if ii not in list1:
            new_list.append(0)
        else:

            print('This is ii ' + ii)
            for y in list1:
                if ii in y:
                    new_list.append(list2[x][0])
    except IndexError:
        new_list.append(0)
print(new_list)
print(len(new_list))
print(len(list1))
print(len(list2))
```

Comment: This produces the correct lengths for both `new_list` and `list1` but it does not order the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['2018-24', '2018-23', '2018-22', '2018-21', '2018-20', '2018-19', '2018-18', '2018-17', '2018-16', '2018-15', '2018-14', '2018-13', '2018-12', '2018-11']

list2 = [(27, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-7'), (5, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-2'), (4, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-6'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-10'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-14'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-50'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-12'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-4'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-5'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-3'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-51'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-13'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-11')]

new_list = [0]*len(list1)

for x in list2:
    i = x[2].split(' ')[2]
    if i in list1:
        new_list[list1.index(i)] = x[0]

print(new_list) #[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

Try initializing the new_list to be a list of 0 and then looking up the index on where to put it in the `new_list` using `.index(value)` with the new value, it's not the most optimized way of doing things but it should get the job done.

---

Why are you wanting to store it like this. It seems to me like you might want to map the values of `new_list` back to `list1` as some sort of look up. If that's the case you might want to consider using a dictionary for key-value pairs look up, it's quicker and better, which is the first line to [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799519/4099813).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I had done something similar a while back but did not think to set the list to contain all '0's as you mentioned was better to use the dict comprehension, originally I wanted to store it like this because I need two lists that are getting sent to my template for the charts.js library, as they need them as lists, this way I can now extract both easily.

Answer (score 0):

**@mp252**, I appreciate the answers of this problem and I've few set of suggestions that I want to share with a simple code example executed on Interactive Python Terminal. Finally, I've answered the question using `map()` and `dictionary comprehension`, it's similar to **Kevin**'s answer.

> Try problem online at http://rextester.com/VODUZ45704.

» Don't use `spit(' ')`, use `split()` to ignore extra spaces.

Have a look at the below sequence of statements executed on Python Interactive Terminal.

```
>>> s = 'Opportunities email 2018-7'
>>> s.split();
['Opportunities', 'email', '2018-7']
>>>
>>> s.split(' ');
['Opportunities', 'email', '2018-7']
>>>
>>> s = 'Opportunities           email    2018-7'
>>> s.split();
['Opportunities', 'email', '2018-7']
>>>
>>> s.split(' ');
['Opportunities', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'email', '', '', '', '2018-7']
>>>
>>> s = '  Opportunities           email    2018-7  '
>>> s.split();
['Opportunities', 'email', '2018-7']
>>>
>>> s.split(' ');
['', '', 'Opportunities', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'email', '', '', '', '2018-7', '', '']
>>>
```

Now, you can try the below code to get the `new_list`.

> - Dictionary is fast as any of its item can be searched in O(1) time and it supports string indexes unlike arrays so we can use it to map `'2018-7'`=>`27`, `2018-2`=>`5` etc.
> - So finally, we can iterate over `list` by looking for the existence of its item as key inside dictionary. If it presents add the corresponding value to `new_list` else add 0.

```
list1 = ['2018-24', '2018-23', '2018-22', '2018-21', '2018-20', '2018-19', '2018-18', '2018-17', '2018-16', '2018-15', '2018-14', '2018-13', '2018-12', '2018-11']

list2 = [(27, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-7'), (5, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-2'), (4, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-6'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-10'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-14'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-50'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-12'), (3, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-4'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-5'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-3'), (2, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2017-51'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-13'), (1, 'Deutsche Bank', 'Opportunities email 2018-11')]

d = {tup[2].split()[2]:tup[0] for tup in list2};
new_list = list(map(lambda date: d[date] if date in d else 0, list1));

print(new_list);
```

» Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```